# Как передать запрос в contoller laravel с помощью axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js

К примеру с компонента vue мне нужна передать запрос в laravel,каким образом я бы смогла это сделать?

Comment: Ты могла бы сделать это изучив документацию `Vue`  изучив документацию `axios`  написав код, применяя знания полученные на первых двух шагах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать пакет axios, это удобная обертка над ajax запросом.

```
 created() {
    axios.get(`http://loacalhost/users/profile`)
    .then(response => {
      // JSON ответ
      this.user = response.data
    })
    .catch(e => {
      // обработка ошибки
      this.errors.push(e)
    })
  }
```

Данный код помещается в блок `script` вашего компонента.
Также необходимо импортировать сам модуль `import axios from 'axios';` для данного компанента, если он не импортируется глобально.

Почитайте больще про данный модуль, вы найдете много примеров